# Creating new queue in MSMQ, messages fall out

Tags: msmq, nservicebus

My office currently utilizes NServiceBus and we plan a release soon in which we will be required to halt a service and move those messages out of its queue for their deferred timeout messages and move them in one by one to test a piece of new functionality. I have attempted to create queues manually and cannot seem to figure out why messages will not remain in the queue after copying. I have created both a transactional and non-transactional version of the queue. I have tried to copy messages from my audit queue into both of the newly created queues and instead those messages fall out into their respective dead-letter queues. I am using an application called Queue Explorer to handle moving messages from one queue to another.

What does NServiceBus do differently when it creates queues that I cannot do manually? Are there any tips someone can offer to alleviate my issues? If anyone has any advice as to what I can try differently, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: What Version of NServiceBus are you running?

Comment: We are using NServiceBus 3.2

Comment: Are you trying to migrate your timeout messages from one endpoint to another?

Comment: (NSeerviceBus creates private transnational queues.)

if they are consumed from the queue it means they are processed by the endpoint, did you check ravenDB's timeout documents?

Comment: Basically, NServiceBus has deferred messages that are queued up to run at 5AM every morning. We are doing a release in which we want to use those messages to test new functionality. Our attempt was to create a queue to move those messages into for holding so they weren't processed by the service. In attempting to manually create a message queue, I tried copying some existing auditing messages into the queue to test, and the messages fell out into the dead letter queue.

Comment: I attempted to make both a transactional and a non-transactional private queue, but ended up with both reacting the same and falling out into their respective dead letter queues. I was wondering what NServiceBus does to create queues that appears to be different than manually creating one. NServiceBus created queues appear to hold messages indefinitely.

Comment: So, i'm trying to get a better understanding of your scenario. endpoint A (current version is running in production) has some timeouts in the timeout queue, and you want to use the timeout messages against your new endpoint A (with updated functionality) on a test machine? is this correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The situation just really lies in the fact that the message queue I am creating doesn't appear to hold messages, they consistently fall out into the dead letter queue, even though nothing is reading from the queue.

Comment: this would probably better suited to discussing on the forum https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/particularsoftware

Comment: This question asking for help to troubleshoot a bug in their program. Does note really fit the the Q+A guidelines of SO. in fact there could be several "correct" answer to help the user fix their problem

Answer (score -1):

The Sample code for sending message using MSMQ

```
        MessageQueue messageQueue = null;
        if (MessageQueue.Exists(@".\Private$\SomeTestName"))
        {
            messageQueue = new MessageQueue(@".\Private$\SomeTestName");
            messageQueue.Label = "Testing Queue";
        }
        else
        {
            // Create the Queue
            MessageQueue.Create(@".\Private$\SomeTestName");
            messageQueue = new MessageQueue(@".\Private$\SomeTestName");
            messageQueue.Label = "Newly Created Queue";
        }
        messageQueue.Send("Teste message sends by bawar", "Title");
```